# Bootstrap not formatting for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

So I am trying to teach myself how to use bootstrap and for some reason I can not get the website to format correctly when displaying on a mobile device. The website is formatting correctly when the browser is resized but not when emulating a mobile device.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link  href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>HERE IS WHERE THE CONTAINER IS. </h1>
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<h2>Paragraph 1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin rutrum leo ut posuere suscipit. Suspendisse sed ex venenatis, tempus quam sit amet, porta sapien. Maecenas in nibh leo. In elementum eleifend odio, id pellentesque justo. Cras vitae placerat mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer faucibus eget nulla eget mollis. Pellentesque interdum vitae purus ut venenatis. Fusce hendrerit ultricies dignissim.</p>
</div><!--col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4-->

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<h2>Paragraph 2</h2>
<p>Duis elementum quam sit amet ante imperdiet, id bibendum nunc finibus. Donec et semper quam, et tempus tellus. Nullam quis nisl eu sem sodales consectetur. Donec ornare urna elit, in euismod leo feugiat eget. In eu placerat tellus. Nullam et tristique purus. Sed ut accumsan ipsum, nec semper mauris.</p>
</div><!--col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4-->

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

<h2>Paragraph 3</h2>
<p>Mauris euismod massa a gravida posuere. Etiam placerat euismod est. Nam sed scelerisque elit. Mauris id ultrices enim. Nulla eu justo eget tellus vestibulum lacinia non eu augue. Maecenas porta purus vitae vehicula mattis. Nam auctor euismod ornare. Morbi eleifend luctus varius. Sed non nisl porta, vehicula elit sed, rhoncus felis. Aliquam ac elementum nunc. Integer blandit porta nisi, et venenatis nibh. Donec velit lorem, aliquet vel lorem in, efficitur tempus leo. Nulla facilisi. Nam vel malesuada mauris. Vivamus leo libero, finibus ut justo eget, tristique lobortis lectus. Etiam luctus urna eget leo lobortis blandit.</p>
</div><!--col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4-->


</div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->

</body>
</html>
```

I have been unable to figure out why this would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: .row-fluid doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3. Use .row. It's all fluid in Bootstrap when you use .container-fluid. Also, you only need col-sm-4 not the others. Other than than, this looks fine and will stack below the col-sm- min-width (anything below 768px will stack with this set up).

Comment: I made the suggested changes and it still is not emulating on a mobile device correctly. Nothing resizes when emulating lets say an iphone 4. It simply has scroll bars and still has the three columns.

Comment: It's fine in iphone and all other small devices. There's probably something wrong with the emulator. You have your viewport meta tag included in the actual thing you're looking at? http://jsbin.com/tijen/1/edit

Comment: Yes I do. But if it is working for you then I agree there is an issue with my emulator. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can get 30 free min. with BrowserStack and I think CrossBrowserTesting.com. It's always good to check on real devices as well but they are good in a pinch. I spend about 50 bucks a month just to get access to IE since I don't want to get another computer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using Bootstrap 2 here, take a look at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-first-with-bootstrap-3--net-34808) on configuring Bootstrap 3 to work on mobile devices.

Comment: No, the only thing he or she used from 2 is .row-fluid the rest was Bootstrap 3.